# How do I print this object to the console so I can access each value on the object by specifying the key?

Tags: flutter, dart

My code looks like this.
This is the function that is returning an object of MyUser.

```
class MyUser{
  final String name;
  String matric;
  final String email;
  final String userType;
  MyUser({
    required this.name, 
    this.matric='', 
    required this.email, 
    required this.userType});

  static Future<Object?> editProfile() async {
    return MyUser(name: 'name', email: 'email', userType: 'userType');
  }
}
```

And the code receiving it aims to print the received object of MyUser like so:

```
Future? editProfile() async {
      Object? userRes = await MyUser.editProfile();
      print(await userRes);
      return null;
    }
```

I want to print the object so I can use the keys to fetch values individually like user['name'] and it should print out name. But all I get is Instance of MyUser. Please help me out here. Thanks.

P.S: I want to know how to print objects like this on an async function.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the right class, not just `Object`. then you can do this

```
static Future<MyUser> editProfile() async {
  return MyUser(name: 'name', email: 'email', userType: 'userType');
}

Future? editProfile() async {
  MyUser userRes = await MyUser.editProfile();
  print(userRes.name);
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this to check all the fields of your custom data:

1. Your case

```
class MyUser{
  String name, email, userType;
  
  MyUser({required this.name, required this.email, required this.userType});

}

void main(){
  MyUser user = MyUser(name: 'test', email: 'test@test.test', userType: 'test');
  print(user);
}
```

And output

```
Instance of 'MyUser'
```

2. New one

```
class MyUser{
  String name, email, userType;
  
  MyUser({required this.name, required this.email, required this.userType});
  
  @override
  String toString(){
    return 'name:' + name + ', email:' + email + ', userType:' + userType;
  }
}

void main(){
  MyUser user = MyUser(name: 'test', email: 'test@test.test', userType: 'test');
  print(user);
}
```

And output

```
name:test, email:test@test.test, userType:test
```